# How to show categorical data on x-axis when using bar function?

Tags: matlab, graph, bar-chart, matlab-figure, axis

I am trying to simulate a code which is on the official MATLAB website, but I cannot get the same output.

This is the code:

```
c = categorical({'apples','oranges','pears'});
prices = [1.23 0.99 2.3];
bar(c,prices)
```

This is the correct output which is on the MATLAB website:

[image: correct output from MatLab website]

This is the output that I get in my MATLAB:

[image: my output from my own MatLab]

The `c` array, which is `apple`, `orange` and `pears` is not showing in my MATLAB output. Why don't I get the same output?

My MATLAB version is R2016a.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. The workaround is fine; but I don't understand why this code, directly from MATLAB's website, isn't working like they say it should. Any insight about that since?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following workaround (as mentioned [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/329953-how-to-create-bar-graph-with-categorical-data?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)):

```
prices = [1.23 0.99 2.3];
bar(prices)
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'apples','oranges','pears'});
```

So, you get rid of `categorical` and switch to the [`gca`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html) function, that allows you to change axis labels.