# GCA function doen't work to change axis-labels

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I try to present 8 (name) labels on my x-axis. Instead, I get number 1 to 8.

**Problem:** In my [previous asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896571/how-to-show-categorical-data-on-x-axis-when-using-bar-function), I used `gca` function, that allows me to change axis labels. However, the same `gca` function doesn't work here.

**This is my MatLab output:**

[image]

**Instead of 1,...8, I want to see Firm1...Firm8!**

**This is my code:**

```
figure(2);
%four variables: 
      %pi --> 8x1 vector
      %E_R_BL_Idzorek --> 8x1 vector
      %pi_star1 --> 8x1 vector
      %ER_100_TF1 --> 8x1 vector

ALL_DATA=[pi(1,1) E_R_BL_Idzorek(1,1) pi_star1(1,1) ER_100_TF1(1,1);pi(2,1) E_R_BL_Idzorek(2,1) pi_star1(2,1) ER_100_TF1(2,1);pi(3,1) E_R_BL_Idzorek(3,1) pi_star1(3,1) ER_100_TF1(3,1);pi(4,1) E_R_BL_Idzorek(4,1) pi_star1(4,1) ER_100_TF1(4,1);pi(5,1) E_R_BL_Idzorek(5,1) pi_star1(5,1) ER_100_TF1(5,1);pi(6,1) E_R_BL_Idzorek(6,1) pi_star1(6,1) ER_100_TF1(6,1);pi(7,1) E_R_BL_Idzorek(7,1) pi_star1(7,1) ER_100_TF1(7,1);pi(8,1) E_R_BL_Idzorek(8,1) pi_star1(8,1),ER_100_TF1(8,1)];

%plotting it with a bar function
bar(ALL_DATA);

%This is where I have problem with gca function
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'Firm1','Firm2','Firm3','Firm4','Firm5','Firm6','Firm7','Firm8'});

%this is the grid part:
grid on
ll = cell(1,4);
ll{1}='pi'; ll{2}='ERidz'; ll{3}='piTF'; ll{4}='ERTF';  
legend(bar(ALL_DATA),ll);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a newer version of MATLAB so you should use the newer graphics system.  The newer system is based on objects.  This makes setting properties of things like axes easier.  For example:

```
fh = figure; % creates the figure window save the figure handle to set it's properties
ax = axes(fh); % creates the axes in the figure, again save the object
x = rand(8,100);
h = bar(ax, x); % create the bar graph in your axes object
% now use the saved object to access the exact feature you want.  This way you always have the thing you want.  No searching.
ax.XTickLabel = {'Firm1','Firm2','Firm3','Firm4','Firm5','Firm6','Firm7','Firm8'};
```

Saving the objects is also handy for tracking legends and other things.  For example:  `legend(ax,...` You know exactly which legend you're dealing with.

What appears to be happening is that you are correctly changing the XTicks as you want but then you overwrite your graph with `legend(bar(...`.  That creates a new `bar` graph.  Try changing that line to just `legend(ll)`.  I would still suggest using the object system.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that you redraw the bar when you run

```
legend(bar(ALL_DATA),ll);
```

You should simply do

```
legend(ll);
```