# Categorical bar graph labels don't work on Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I tried this code to get a categorical label on the bottom of my bar graph:

```
c = categorical({'apples','oranges','pears'});
prices = [1.23 0.99 2.3];
bar(c,prices)
```

In the MATLAB documentation, this claims to have the bottom of the axis labelled with the categories in `c`. Instead I only see 1, 2, 3 along the bottom. Is something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show categorical data on x-axis when using bar function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896571/how-to-show-categorical-data-on-x-axis-when-using-bar-function)

Comment: @SardarUsama true, it is. Thanks for showing this. Still, that post doesn't have a good explanation of why the function isn't working as shown in MATLAB's documentation; rather it has a workaround suggestion instead. Any ideas on why it doesn't work this way?

Comment: Read the documentation of [the version](https://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html) that you actually have. Not sure about R2016b, but what you're trying to do wasn't introduced till R2016a.

Comment: I am actually using R2016b, so I'm not sure why it won't work.

Comment: Do you see that code in the documentation of *R2016b*?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was only introduced in Matlab 2017a. As you can see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2016b/matlab/ref/bar.html#examples) it is absent from 2016b docs:

[image]